# Unable to display the data into textfield using redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I'm trying to update my data but them problem is unable to display the data into Texfield. But in console log or network the data are display. Please see below my code.

Please anyone help. Thanks

// Update Form

```
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userInfo = useSelector(selectUser);

  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(userInfo);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUser(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      setUserData(userInfo);
    }
  }, [userInfo]);


<TextField name="name" value={userInfo?.name || ''} />
<TextField name="email" value={userInfo?.email|| ''} />
```

// User Slice

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: userInfo: null,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(getUser.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.isError = false;
        state.userInfo = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(getUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
        toast.error(action.payload);
      })

export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.userInfo;
```

Comment: what does `userInfo` has when logged ?

Comment: it will display the data that I want to update.